# LAN->OpenVPN Client

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, nat, untangle

I have an Untangle NG Firewall set up. I'd like to access an OpenVPN client from a LAN IP.

OpenVPN Client is on 192.168.3.x
Regular LAN is on 192.168.2.x

At the moment, the OpenVPN Client can connect to any IP address on the regular LAN, but it does not appear that the regular LAN nodes can connect to any of the OpenVPN Client nodes...

I tried to set a route on network 192.168.3.0/24 with a next-hop of 192.168.2.1 (the Untangle gateway IP), but got a strange error that stopped all communication from 3.x to 2.x.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with untangle NG firewall so I am only suggesting you something to try: `I tried to set a route on network 192.168.3.0/24 with a next-hop of 192.168.2.1`, did you set the route on the client machine (the machine on the LAN)? If not try setting up that route on the client machine (instead of the Firewall itself)

Comment: @MichaelYin Not sure if that would work, I don't know of any routing configuration on the client side. Perhaps a subnet has something to do with it?

Comment: E.g. if it's a Windows client: `route ADD 192.168.3.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.1` (copied from https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/ )